Adding string into Barcode string
I want to add 0 into barcode string ABC4DE. So the output looks like 0ABC4DE.
Here is my code.
        string nZero = "0";
        if (tbReadBarcode2.Text.Contains("\r\n"))
        {
            tbReadBarcode2.Text = tbReadBarcode2.Text.Replace("\r\n", nZero + "");
            btnReadBarcode2.Background = Brushes.Green;
            bool result = false;

With this code, the final barcode string looks like this ABC4DE0 instead of 0ABC4DE.
The "0" was added at behind instead in front.
Can anyone help?
0ABC4DE and not ABC4DE0

tbReadBarcode2.Text = "0" + tbReadBarcode2.Text.Replace("\r\n", "")

To me, it seems like you just need to split on carriage return and newline, remove the empty entries, and then padleft the given text to your desired length with "0"

You are attempting to replace the newline characters "\r\n" with "0", which is not present in the string.
This should fix the issue :
string nZero = "0";
tbReadBarcode2.Text = nZero + tbReadBarcode2.Text;
btnReadBarcode2.Background = Brushes.Green;
bool result = false;


Try this:
string nZero = "0";
if (tbReadBarcode2.Text.Contains("\r\n"))
{
    tbReadBarcode2.Text = nZero + tbReadBarcode2.Text.Replace("\r\n", "");
    btnReadBarcode2.Background = Brushes.Green;
    bool result = false;
}


Please explain how this actually solves the issue
